# Casting a bytearray containing 11-bit integers to an array of 16-bit integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, ctypes

I have a bytes object or bytearray object representing a packed stream of 11-bit integers. (Edit: Stream is 11-bit big-endian integers without padding.)

Is there a reasonably efficient way of copying this to a stream of 16-bit integers? Or any other integer type?

I know that ctypes supports bit fields but I am not sure whether this helps me here at all.

Can I maybe "abuse" some part of the standard library that already does such bit-fiddling for other purposes?

If I have to resort to cython, is there an good implementation that can deal with variable bit-lengths? I.e. not only for 11 bit input but also 12, 13, etc?

---

**Edit:** Pure python solution based on PM2 Ring's answer

```
def unpackIntegers(data, num_points, bit_len):
    """Unpacks an array of integers of arbitrary bit-length into a 
    system-word aligned array of integers"""
    # TODO: deal with native integer types separately for speedups
    mask = (1 << bit_len) - 1

    unpacked_bit_len = 2 ** ceil(log(bit_len, 2))
    unpacked_byte_len = ceil(unpacked_bit_len / 8)
    unpacked_array = bytearray(num_points * unpacked_byte_len)
    unpacked = memoryview(unpacked_array).cast(
        FORMAT_CODES[unpacked_byte_len])

    num_blocks = num_points // 8 

    # Note: zipping generators is faster than calculating offsets 
    #       from a block count
    for idx1_start, idx1_stop, idx2_start, idx2_stop in zip(
            range(0, num_blocks*bit_len, bit_len),
            range(bit_len, (num_blocks+1)*bit_len, bit_len),
            range(7, num_points, 8),
            range(-1, num_points-8, 8),
            ):
        n = int.from_bytes(data[idx1_start:idx1_stop], 'big')
        for i in range(idx2_start, idx2_stop, -1):
            unpacked[i] = n & mask
            n >>= bit_len
    # process left-over part (missing from PM2 Ring's answer)
    else:
        points_left = num_points % 8 
        bits_left = points_left * bit_len
        bytes_left = len(data)-num_blocks*bit_len
        num_unused_bits = bytes_left * 8 - bits_left

        n = int.from_bytes(data[num_blocks*bit_len:], 'big')
        n >>= num_unused_bits
        for i in range(num_points-1, num_points-points_left-1, -1):
            unpacked[i] = n & mask
            n >>= bit_len
    return unpacked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way to do this with a 3rd-party library, but here's one way to do it with standard Python.

The `unpack` generator iterates over its `data` argument in chunks, `data` can be any iterable that yields bytes. To unpack 11 bit data we read chunks of 11 bytes, combine those bytes into a single integer, and then we slice that integer into 8 pieces, so each piece will contain the data from the corresponding 11 source bits.

```
def unpack(data, bitlen):
    mask = (1 << bitlen) - 1
    for chunk in zip(*[iter(data)] * bitlen):
        n = int.from_bytes(chunk, 'big')
        a = []
        for i in range(8):
            a.append(n & mask)
            n >>= bitlen
        yield from reversed(a)

# Test

# 0 to 23 in 11 bit integers, packed into bytes
data = bytes([
    0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 48, 8, 1, 64, 48, 7, 
    1, 0, 36, 5, 0, 176, 24, 3, 64, 112, 15, 
    2, 0, 68, 9, 1, 48, 40, 5, 64, 176, 23,
])

print(list(unpack(data, 11)))
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Note that if `data` does not contain a multiple of `bitlen` bytes then it will end in a partial chunk which will be ignored.